# Autopopulate company name in lead conversion page in lightning

Tags: lightning, lead-conversion

We have a client where they use lightning. When they click convert, the company name from the lead does not autopopulate on the conversion page. They have to retype the company name and search for companies or add a new company which is annoying. Is there a hack to override the current lead conversion page to autopopulate the company name on the lightning conversion page?
Buyan

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to override this as of now. One solution is to skip the standard lead conversion screen and use a custom visualforce page or component for this.